# gradle build is failing when i have multiple tasks with run time parameters

Tags: gradle

In my gradle build have multiple tasks and i am passing parameters run time. build is getting failed when i am doing a gradle build

Below are the two tasks which take parameters run time

Task1

```
task downloadFile(type: MyDownload) {
    sourceUrl = srcUrl
    target = new File(destUrl, 'build.zip')
}
```

Task2

```
task unzip(type: Copy) {
    def zipFile = file(zipFileInput)
    def outputDir = file(zipFileOutput)

    from zipTree(zipFile)
    into outputDir
}
```

Please suggest a solution to fix the issue

Comment: What errors? What inputs?

Comment: i am running task like this gradle unzip -PzipFileInput="location of the file" -PzipFileOutput="location of the file"

Comment: i am getting below error while running gradle build                                                               Could not get unknown property 'zipFileInput' for root project 'mldata2' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access project properties inside a task, you need to call those properties on the project itself.

```
task unzip(type: Copy) {
    doLast {
      def zipFile = file(project.zipFileInput)
      def outputDir = file(project.zipFileOutput)

      from zipTree(zipFile)
      into outputDir
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to pass the values only when i am running the task through command line as an argument

Comment: @Ramz what's the problem?

Comment: i need to call gradle task in my jenkins pipeline and pass the parametes. is it possible?